# How does term 'cardinality' differs from 'relation' in data-modeling?

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling, relational-database, database-schema

Can you describe: How does term 'cardinality' differs from 'relation' in data-modeling?

Comment: I'd describe it as untagged homework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are completely different concepts (a bit like asking what's the difference between "addition" and "zero" in arithmetic), so it's difficult to explain any "difference" other than to simply suggest looking up their definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Cardinality relates the rate of occurrence of a value in a table column. Whereas relation defines link(s) between two tables through one or more fields.

Agree with Marcelo though. Comparing those two terms if like comparing apples and oranges.